# Spring circular dependance with scope PROTOTYPE

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, spring-bean

I created below scenario to understand Spring Circular dependancy.

Its clean when scope is singleton. But conflict occur when S**COPE is PROTOTYPE.**

So I want to know Is Spring support avoid below scenario or should we change the design. if so please propose some design.

Consider below example.

```
@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class BeanB {

    private BeanA beanA;

    @Autowired
    public void setBeanA(BeanA beanA) {
        this.beanA = beanA;
    }

    public void printBeanB() {
        System.out.println(getBeanName());
    }

    public void printBeanBBeanA() {
        System.out.println(getBeanName() + " - " + beanA.getBeanName());
    }

    public String getBeanName() {
        return "Bean B";
    }
}


@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class BeanA {

    private BeanB beanB;

    @Autowired
    public void setBeanB(BeanB beanB) {
        this.beanB = beanB;
    }

    public void printBeanA() {
        System.out.println(getBeanName());
    }

    public void printBeanABeanB() {
        System.out.println(getBeanName() + " - " + beanB.getBeanName());
    }

    public String getBeanName() {
        return "Bean A";
    }
}
```

This is give an error :

> Description:
>
> The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form
>   a cycle:
>
> demoApplication (field private com.example.demo.beans.BeanA
>   com.example.demo.DemoApplication.beanA)

So Is Spring support avoid this or should we change the design. if so please propose some design.

Answer (score 2):

I could be able to resolve this by using @Lazy annotation as below.

```
@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class BeanA {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private BeanB beanB;
    public void printBeanA() {
        System.out.println(getBeanName());
    }

    public void printBeanABeanB() {
        System.out.println(getBeanName() + " - " + beanB.getBeanName());
    }

    public String getBeanName() {
        return "Bean A";
    }
}

@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class BeanB {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private BeanA beanA;

    public void setBeanA(BeanA beanA) {
        this.beanA = beanA;
    }

    public void printBeanB() {
        System.out.println(getBeanName());
    }

    public void printBeanBBeanA() {
        System.out.println(getBeanName() + " - " + beanA.getBeanName());
    }

    public String getBeanName() {
        return "Bean B";
    }
}
```